# Invoking a command inside a command without knowing the parameters in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

When I need to invoke a command in discord.py rewrite i need to pass the argument it takes equal to a value

like for invoking the command **!say** with argument '**hi**' (i.e, !say hi)

```py
@commands.command()
async def say(self, ctx, msg):
   await ctx.send(msg)
```

i need the **parameter** "msg"

```py
@commands.command()
async def inv(self, ctx):
   await ctx.invoke(self.bot.get_command('say'),msg='hi')
```

but im trying to make a general invoke-command
i know how to get the name of the command so i just need to know how do i get the **arguments** required by the command and how can i use it inside **invoke**

```py
@commands.command()
async def playtest(self, ctx):
   await ctx.invoke(self.bot.get_command('nameofcommand'),<parameter>='hi')
```

even using **variables** here will just not work

```py
x = 'msg'
@commands.command()
async def inv(self, ctx):
   await ctx.invoke(self.bot.get_command('say'),x = 'hi')
```

Comment: Why not just call the method? `await self.say(ctx, "Hi")`

Comment: @JoshuaNixon That doesn't work so it seems like invoke is the only way

Comment: It does work because I do the same kind of thing in my bot. I suggest reading the documentation as it has everything you need. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @JoshuaNixon 
await self.say(ctx, "Hi")
gives
Command raised an exception: TypeError: say() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Answer (score 0):

Like Joshua said, you can do `await say(ctx, "a")` inside the class you initialized your `say` function or if your `say` function is not in any class (if that's the case then remove the `self` argument)

Example:

```py
class a(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def say(self, ctx, msg):
        await ctx.send(msg)

    @commands.command()
    async def bruh(self, ctx):
        await self.say(ctx, "this was called by bruh command")
```

If you want to call the function **outside** the class, you have to do `await say(bot, ctx, "message")` which `bot` is the variable you used to initialize the bot